# LG V10 Mysterious Shutdown Loop

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, boot, lg

My phone is stuck in the strangest bootloop I've ever encountered. Last night my phone dropped to 0% battery, so I charged it on up and restarted it. I didn't look at it for a while but when I did it notified me of the phone being updated.

Weird, no updates in the pipeline, when I go to check it says I haven't downloaded a new one in months. Then my phone starts restarting. A couple second freeze, and then it's starting back up. Boots all the way up, then my background apps start up. Minute later, phone's restarting again. The phone keeps this up all night, and into the next morning, varying in the amount of time between boots and crashes

Okay, boot in safe mode, no difference. Clear cache partition, no difference. Factory reset via UI, no difference. Factory reset from boot menu, no difference. Put it in the fridge for 30 minutes, no difference. Wanna hear the weird part?

I decided to discharge the battery all the way, and charge it all the way back up. Might as well, right? Unfortunately at some point my phone decided to start shutting down and staying off, instead of restarting. Shit, well I guess I'll just have to keep starting it up. So I throw on a muted repeating youtube playlist, turned the screen brightness up, and it just keeps going... It plays the videos happily without crashing. When you leave youtube it eventually crashes.

Seems to me like a piece of software in the main OS that starts late in the boot cycle which crashes things and doesn't get factory reset (and youtube stops it from starting?).

So, is there anything I can try beyond flashing the original firmware?

Comment: You should just go ahead and try flashing the original firmware. Many G4/V10/Nexus5X units are susceptible to the infamous motherboard solder defect that would throw the device into a bootloop, and from the description yours seem to be one of those. Flashing the original firmware is not a fix, it just serves as the final step to determine whether it's a hardware fault (you've done most previous steps).

Comment: I am almost entirely positive this is not a motherboard solder defect. I am pretty convinced this is a software issue, as being able to run youtube for 5+ hours with no issue, only to have it crash upon exit suggests. I am currently trying a scientific approach to uninstalling software that came with the device to see if I can find the exact culprit. Results positive so far.